# Python: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/Documents/1'

Tags: python

[image: Error]

I am trying to read the sub folders in a folder (D:/Documents/), open the word documents in those sub folders, count the number of lines and if the count is greater than 2 I would like to move the sub folder into a respective sub folder of a destination folder named (D:/copied-folders/) with the same file names. But I am being thrown an error (PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/Documents/1').

Below is the code written in Jupyter workbook:

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
import bs4
import requests
count = 0
src = 'D://Documents/'
dest = 'D://copied-folders//'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:/Documents/', topdown=False):
    #for name in files:
        #os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:        
        #print(os.path.join(root, name))
        dir = os.path.join(root, name)
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        #count = 0
        for line in open(os.path.join(root, name), encoding='latin-1'):
            count += 1
            pos = 'out'
        print("Line Count:", count)
        if count > 2:
            #stat = os.close(1)
            #print(stat)
            #shutil.copy(name, dest)
            #path1 = os.path.join(root)
            #print(os.path.basename(path1))
            #os.path.relpath('D://Documents/')
            path = os.path.join(root)
            print(os.path.basename(path))
            #p = os.path.basename(path)
            shutil.copyfile(path, dest)
        else:
            continue
```

Also attached is the screenshot of the error I came across. I am new to Python.

Comment: Is the file open in another application?

Comment: No. Guess I have to close it in this application

Comment: `path = os.path.join(root)` ???

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import shutil

count = 0
src = 'stack_files'
dest = 'stack_files/stack_files_out'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=False):

    for name in dirs:

        dir = os.path.join(root, name)
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))

        for line in open(os.path.join(root, name), encoding='latin-1'):
            count += 1
            pos = 'out'
            print("Line Count:", count)
            if count > 2:

                shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(root,name), os.path.join(dest,name))
            continue
```

you are giving folder path to copy , shutil.copy() is used to copy file only , we need to provide the complete path , cross check the path that is being sent to shutil function

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207426/discussion-on-answer-by-manoj-yadav-python-permissionerror-errno-13-permissi).